# Why do we need to specify the domain of an unbounded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am learning about the fluid dynamics and I cam across the following phrase as I was reading about the Stokes operator on Wikipedia.

"Since the Stokes operator is unbounded, we must give its domain of definition"

What does the unboundeness of an operator have to do with its domain?

Comment: Whenever you define a function, you have to make explicit its domain.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez But, why does the Wiki say "since the operator is unbounded"?

Comment: No idea. You **always** have to say what the domain is.

Comment: a bounded linear operator is continuous everywhere on the Banach space, conversely an unbounded linear operator $x \to T[x]$ cannot be continuous on the hypersphere $||x||$ : it has a singularity somewhere on any hypersphere $||x||=R$ : it is not defined everywhere.

Comment: @user1952009, that is not true. An unbounded operator may well be defined "everywhere".

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez : not in a complete metric space, so to simplify lets consider the space complete (even if for another norm it can be be well-defined and bounded, but again to simplify, ...)

Comment: That is absurd. Any linear map from a subspace of a Banach space $X$ to another Banach space $Y$, bounded or not, can be extended to a linear map $X\to Y$ defined on the whole of $X$. If the original one was not bounded, neither is the new one.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez : the Fourier transform of the completed $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ space in singular at the dirac whose Fourier transform is not $L^1$. what I explained is the intuitive idea to understand what he read, what is absurd is not to say it as I did.

Comment: I simply cannot tell what relation there is between that and the OP's question.

Comment: @Mariano : I'm thinking you missed something. in the completed Banach space, if the operator is unbounded, it is unbounded on $||x||=1$ and thus there is a sequence $||x_n||=1$ such that $||T x_n|| \to \infty$ : $T$ has a singularity there, even if for another norm it might be bounded and well-defined for that sequence $x_n$ (and for its limit $x = _lim_n x_n$).

Comment: If I had to guess, OP's context probably required a bounded operator, so it would have been more clear to say "we must restrict its domain of definition"

Comment: @user1952009, that has nothing To do with anything.

Comment: @user1952009 If your operator $T$ is not closed then it is possible for $x_n \rightarrow x$ such that $\| Tx_n\| \rightarrow \infty$, but $Tx$ is still defined.

Comment: @user1952009: The unit ball is not compact in an arbitrary Banach space, and so the $x_n$ in your sequence may not contain a convergent subsequence. Consider, for example, the map $T:\ell^\infty \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $Te_i = i$ for the obvious basis $\{e_1, e_2, \dots\}$.

Comment: @anomaly : I said there is a sequence, not all the sequences. the intuitive idea is just that there is point on $||x||=1$ at which an unbounded linear operator on a complete Banach space is non-continuous, and that point can be seen as a singularity of the operator, not a "simple discontinuity point"

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think the primary confusion/point is that if one is talking about an operator it is usually implicit that it is acting on a certain Banach space. Since closed unbounded operators defined on the entire Banach space do not exist, one is in the situation that the operator one is considering is defined on some subspace (for closed unbounded operators), and when presenting it one can no longer suppress mentioning the domain as there no longer is a canonical answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost always one studies closed operators. In fact, you rarely can do much of anything with an operator that is not closable. Closed operators that are everywhere defined on a Banach space are continuous by the closed graph theorem. So the best you can hope for is that the operator is densely-defined; that leaves you having to specify the precise domain, which usually involves boundary conditions for differential operators.

Answer (score 0):

An old result of functional analysis tells us that a symmetric, unbounded operator acting on a Hilbert space cannot be defined on the whole space but only in a dense subspace of it. It is a direct consequence of the Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem. (see for example: Riesz-Nagy, "Functional Analysis", 1955 and also Reed-Simon, "Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics", 1975).  As a consequence of this result, the investigation of the domains of such operators has always been a delicate topic especially in problems of Mathematical Physics.

On the other hand, if an operator is defined on the whole of the space, then its domain is trivial.

Comment: There must be a missing assumption here. If you take a densely defined linear map you could extend it to be defined on the whole space using Zorn's lemma.

Comment: You end with «...then its domain is trivial», with  weird sense of the word *trivial*!

Comment: @ Christopher A. Wong: in general you are right. The missing assumption is that the operator should also be symmetric. In this case  (symmetric + unbounded) the operator cannot be defined on the whole of the Hilbert space. this is a direct consequence of the Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem. Since the operators of interest in physics are self-adjoint ($\Rightarrow$ symmetric) they fall into this. The Stokes operator is self-adjoint. I guess this implies that the extension of such operators on the whole of the space (using the AC), produces non-symmetric (and thus non-self-adjoint) operators.

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: I just meant that its domain is by definition the whole of the space so it is trivial to mention. Sorry if I caused some confusion using the word "trivial" in this manner.